# How to Change Content-Type Python

Tags: python, post, content-type

I want to upload a file to a remote device.
If i look up the connection with wireshark i get this

```
POST /saveRestore.htm.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.128.115.214
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://10.128.115.214/saveRestore.htm
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------961265085509552220604142744
Content-Length: 10708

-----------------------------961265085509552220604142744
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="restore"; filename="config(2).cfg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Now this says that that the browser only accepts text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

If i upload the file with my script it says

```
--0a7125aebb8845ba8ab9aa21306b01f6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="restore"; filename="Config.cfg"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

So it's a wrong file type..

so how do i change the content-type of the File ?

My code looks so far as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib
import urllib2
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
import poster
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
register_openers()

params = {'restore': open("Config.cfg", "rb"), 'upload': 'PC ==>; Unit'}

datagen, headers = multipart_encode(params)

request = urllib2.Request('http://10.128.115.214/saveRestore.htm.cgi', datagen, headers)
u = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print u.read()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrong Content type when transfering file with Python (poster)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669274/wrong-content-type-when-transfering-file-with-python-poster)

Comment: this is totally unclear. what is the server and what is the client, where do you set the content type/disposition ?

Comment: Server is 10.128.115.214 the saveRestore.htm.cgi is a Web interface for Uploading and restoring files... And i try to do that with a script and not over the Webinterface... and the 1 wireshark comes if I do the uplaod with the webinterface... and the Content-Type of the file is wrong when i do this with the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation for `poster.encode.MultipartParam`](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/poster.encode.html#poster.encode.MultipartParam) it says:

> If `filetype` is set, it is used as the Content-Type for this parameter. If unset it defaults to “text/plain; charset=utf8”

So instead of specifying your parameters like this:

```
params = {'restore': open("Config.cfg", "rb"), 'upload': 'PC ==>; Unit'}
```

specify them like this:

```
params = [MultipartParam('restore', open("Config.cfg", "rb"),
                         filetype = 'application/octet-stream'),
          ('upload', 'PC ==>; Unit')]
```